# Query posts by custom field parent

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, visual-composer

I'm struggling on querying posts in wordpress, precisely - i have a dropdown select field in visual composer widget and what i can select are IDs of parents of custom fields in custom post.
To be more precise - i made custom post - cummunique - witch have custom field - regions - whitch is a list of checkboxes, and this custom field(regions) has subregions.
It looks like this:

- SOME MAIN REGION

  - some subregion
  - some subregion
- ANOTHER MAIN REGION

  - another subregion

    - some sub sub region
  - another subregion

Ofc wordpress admin can check some subregion only without checking main region and like i said in dropdown select of visual composer i can choose only main region id.

So when i choose from dropdown for example * SOME MAIN REGION i want to get only posts that have checked subregions that belongs to this main region.

- SOME MAIN REGION -> id is * some subregion parent id.

Is there a way that i can build meta_query to get these posts?

Thanks for any help!